# "SHMLBA undeclared error" at compilation of "PF_RING-5.2.1" module for Linux (kernel - 3.4.103)

Tags: c, linux-kernel, kernel-module

I can compile *PF_RING-5.2.1  module*  for linux kernel **3.0.4** without any problem. For the "**3.4.103**" kernel however, the following compilation error arises:

```
*.../pf_ring.c: In function 'ring_alloc_mem': enter code hereerror: 'SHMLBA' undeclared (first use in this function)
```

I have already checked that several declarations/references of SHMLBA
 are present in the kernel module like following:

```
 - ./build/ipc/shm.c:    if (addr & (SHMLBA-1)) {
  - ./build/ipc/shm.c:        addr &= ~(SHMLBA-1);     /* round down */
  - ./build/ipc/shm.c:#ifndef __ARCH_FORCE_SHMLBA
  - ./build/drivers/gpu/drm/drm_bufs.c: if (shm && (SHMLBA > PAGE_SIZE))    {
  - ./build/drivers/gpu/drm/drm_bufs.c:   int bits = ilog2(SHMLBA >>    PAGE_SHIFT) + 1;
  - ./build/drivers/gpu/drm/drm_bufs.c:   /* For shared memory, we have    to preserve the SHMLBA
  - ./build/drivers/gpu/drm/drm_bufs.c:    * Therefore, make sure the    SHMLBA relevant bits of the
  - ./build/include/linux/shm.h:#define SHM_RND   020000  /* round attach    address to SHMLBA boundary */
  - ./build/include/asm-generic/shmparam.h:#define SHMLBA PAGE_SIZE  /*    attach addr a multiple of this */
  - ./build/arch/sparc/include/asm/shmparam_64.h:#define    __ARCH_FORCE_SHMLBA  1
  - ./build/arch/sparc/include/asm/shmparam_64.h:#define  SHMLBA ((PAGE_SIZE > 1DCACHE_SIZE) ? PAGE_SIZE : L1DCACHE_SIZE)
  - ./build/arch/sparc/include/asm/shmparam_32.h:#define    __ARCH_FORCE_SHMLBA  1
  - ./build/arch/sparc/include/asm/shmparam_32.h:#define SHMLBA    (vac_cache_size ? vac_cache_size : \
  - ./build/arch/sparc/kernel/sys_sparc_64.c: unsigned long base =    (addr+SHMLBA-1)&~(SHMLBA-1);
  - ./build/arch/sparc/kernel/sys_sparc_64.c: unsigned long off =    (pgoff<<PAGE_SHIFT) & (SHMLBA-1);
  - ./build/arch/sparc/kernel/sys_sparc_64.c: unsigned long base = addr &    ~(SHMLBA-1);
  - ./build/arch/sparc/kernel/sys_sparc_64.c: unsigned long off =    (pgoff<<PAGE_SHIFT) & (SHMLBA-1);
  - ./build/arch/sparc/kernel/sys_sparc_64.c:       ((addr - (pgoff <<    PAGE_SHIFT)) & (SHMLBA - 1)))
  - ./build/arch/sparc/kernel/sys_sparc_64.c:       ((addr - (pgoff <<    PAGE_SHIFT)) & (SHMLBA - 1)))
  - ./build/arch/sparc/kernel/sys_sparc_32.c:#define COLOUR_ALIGN(addr)      (((addr)+SHMLBA-1)&~(SHMLBA-1))
  - ./build/arch/sparc/kernel/sys_sparc_32.c:       ((addr - (pgoff <<    PAGE_SHIFT)) & (SHMLBA - 1)))
  - ./build/arch/x86/include/asm/shmparam.h:#define SHMLBA PAGE_SIZE   /*    attach addr a multiple of this */
  - ./build/arch/ia64/include/asm/shmparam.h: * SHMLBA controls minimum    alignment at which shared memory segments
  - ./build/arch/ia64/include/asm/shmparam.h: * To reduce the chance of    this, we set SHMLBA to 1MB. --davidm 00/12/20
  - ./build/arch/ia64/include/asm/shmparam.h:#define  SHMLBA  (1024*1024)
  - ./build/arch/ia64/kernel/sys_ia64.c:    align_mask = SHMLBA - 1;
  - ./build/arch/alpha/include/asm/shmparam.h:#define SHMLBA PAGE_SIZE       /* attach addr a multiple of this */
  - ./build/arch/mips/include/asm/shmparam.h:#define __ARCH_FORCE_SHMLBA     1
  - ./build/arch/mips/include/asm/shmparam.h:#define  SHMLBA 0x40000         /* attach addr a multiple of this */
  - ./build/arch/m32r/include/asm/shmparam.h:#define  SHMLBA PAGE_SIZE       /* attach addr a multiple of this */
  - ./build/arch/avr32/include/asm/shmparam.h:#define SHMLBA PAGE_SIZE     /* attach addr a multiple of this */
  - ./build/arch/mn10300/include/asm/shmparam.h:#define SHMLBA PAGE_SIZE     /* attach addr a multiple of this */
  - ./build/arch/s390/include/asm/shmparam.h:#define SHMLBA PAGE_SIZE        /* attach addr a multiple of this */
  - ./build/arch/powerpc/include/asm/shmparam.h:#define SHMLBA PAGE_SIZE     /* attach addr a multiple of this */
  - ./build/arch/arm/include/asm/cacheflush.h:#define CACHE_COLOUR(vaddr)    ((vaddr & (SHMLBA - 1)) >> PAGE_SHIFT)
  - ./build/arch/arm/include/asm/shmparam.h:#define SHMLBA  (4 *    PAGE_SIZE)    /* attach addr a multiple of this */
  - ./build/arch/arm/include/asm/shmparam.h: * Enforce SHMLBA in shmat
  - ./build/arch/arm/include/asm/shmparam.h:#define __ARCH_FORCE_SHMLBA
  - ./build/arch/arm/mm/copypage-v6.c:#if SHMLBA > 16384
  - ./build/arch/arm/mm/mmap.c: unsigned long base = addr & ~(SHMLBA-1);
  - ./build/arch/arm/mm/mmap.c: unsigned long off = (pgoff << PAGE_SHIFT)    & (SHMLBA-1);
  - ./build/arch/arm/mm/mmap.c: ((((addr)+SHMLBA-1)&~(SHMLBA-1)) +  \
  - ./build/arch/arm/mm/mmap.c:  (((pgoff)<<PAGE_SHIFT) & (SHMLBA-1)))
  - ./build/arch/arm/mm/mmap.c: * SHMLBA bytes.
  - ./build/arch/arm/mm/mmap.c:       (addr - (pgoff << PAGE_SHIFT)) &    (SHMLBA - 1))
  - ./build/arch/arm/mm/mmap.c:       (addr - (pgoff << PAGE_SHIFT)) &    (SHMLBA - 1))
  - ./build/arch/xtensa/include/asm/shmparam.h:#define SHMLBA ((PAGE_SIZE > DCACHE_WAY_SIZE)? PAGE_SIZE : DCACHE_WAY_SIZE)
  - ./build/arch/parisc/include/asm/shmparam.h:#define    __ARCH_FORCE_SHMLBA  1
  - ./build/arch/parisc/include/asm/shmparam.h:#define SHMLBA 0x00400000     /* attach addr needs to be 4 Mb aligned */
  - ./build/arch/parisc/kernel/cache.c:   if (old_addr == 0 || (old_addr    & (SHMLBA - 1)) != (addr & (SHMLBA - 1))) {
  - ./build/arch/parisc/kernel/sys_parisc.c:#define DCACHE_ALIGN(addr)    (((addr) + (SHMLBA - 1)) &~ (SHMLBA - 1))
  - ./build/arch/m68k/include/asm/shmparam.h:#define  SHMLBA PAGE_SIZE       /* attach addr a multiple of this */
  - ./build/arch/frv/include/asm/shmparam.h:#define SHMLBA PAGE_SIZE        /* attach addr a multiple of this */
  - ./build/arch/sh/include/asm/shmparam.h:#define  SHMLBA  0x4000     /*    attach addr a multiple of this */
  - ./build/arch/sh/include/asm/shmparam.h:#define __ARCH_FORCE_SHMLBA
  - ./build/arch/cris/include/asm/shmparam.h:#define  SHMLBA PAGE_SIZE       /* attach addr a multiple of this */
  - ./build/arch/unicore32/include/asm/cacheflush.h:#define    CACHE_COLOUR(vaddr) ((vaddr & (SHMLBA - 1)) >> PAGE_SHIFT)
  - ./build/arch/h8300/include/asm/shmparam.h:#define SHMLBA PAGE_SIZE       /* attach addr a multiple of this */
  - ./build/mm/vmalloc.c: ret = __vmalloc_node(size, SHMLBA,
  - ./build/Documentation/cachetlb.txt:If your D-cache has this problem,    first define asm/shmparam.h SHMLBA
```

Besides, all of them (above paths) cover the ones that are in kernel **3.0.4**(which i had managed to compile for).

What could be wrong? Any help would be appreciated.